# ring homomorphism vs module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

When $R=F[x]$,

the ring homomorphism $\phi:f(x) \mapsto f(x^2)$ is not an $F[x]-$module homomorphism

Can someone explain why the map is a ring homomorphism? There is something notationally I don't understand.

$f(x+y)=(x+y)^2=x^2 +2xy +y^2 \neq x^2 + y^2 = f(x) + f(y)$ but thats not what the not notation means.

The explanation for why is not a module homomorphism is

$x^2 = \phi(x)=\phi(x*1)=x\phi(1)=x$

But I'm missing something with the notation for this to make sense. Shouldn't $\phi$ take in $f(x)$ or is $f(x)=x?$

Comment: You are applying $\phi$ in the wrong argument.  $\phi((f+g)(x))= (f+g)(x^2) =f(x^2)+g(x^2) = \phi(f(x)) + \phi(g(x))$ to check additivity, not $f(x+y)$.

Comment: Given a polynomial $p = \sum_{i \geq 0} a_ix^i \in R$, $\phi$ takes it to the polynomial $\phi(p) = \sum_{i \geq 0} a_ix^{2i} \in R$.  What you need to prove is that $\phi(p_1+p_2) = \phi(p_1) + \phi(p_2)$ for any $p_1$ and $p_2$ in $R$.

Comment: Okay I'm not sure I understand what $\phi : f(x) \mapsto f(x^2)$ means, but if I understand the manipulations, $\phi((fg)(x))=(fg)(x^2) = (f(x^2))(g(x^2))=\phi(f(x^2))\phi(g(x^2)))$

Comment: You take $f(x)=x^3+1$ for example and get back $f(x^2) = (x^2)^3+1 = x^6+1$.  So $\phi(x^3+1) = x^6+1$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.